# firebug error : no element found

Tags: javascript, xml, servlets

**1** client : send request to server via AJAX fn.

**2** Server : response in form of `text/xml` and it works correctly only 1 or 2 times
       `response.setContentType("text/xml");`

**3** but only after 1/2 request, i get error in browser (firebug) and it says `No element found`

client : `javascript jQuery ajax`
server : `java servlet`

can somebody give any tips to sort out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can somebody give any tips to sort out.

Look at the HTTP traffic. Figure out if the problem is because of a broken request or a broken response. That will tell you if you need to investigate the server side or the client side code.

Comment: wow.. great, thanks Quentin, i am getting error in response (XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal: ..... }  But now i don't understand how to remove this error while i don't see any missing/error in server side  programming

Comment: The *server* is outputting an error message saying that it can't parse the XML? So you are including an XML document in the **request**?

Comment: no no...server isn't but it's firebug error console tells. the process is as follows ` sending request from client(xmlRequest) & getting xml data from server` it's server which sending something missing/broken xml

Comment: @Bibhaw — See my answer: *Look at the HTTP traffic* — Stop looking the errors that come up when you try to process the response with JavaScript and look at what the response actually is (and the request that triggered it).

Comment: Thanks  Quentin, it resolved now. error occurred due to broken response

Comment: I had same problem and i found it`s Mozilla core bug - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=884693

Answer (score 2):

Setting the mimeType to "text/html" fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Put a semicolon at the end of your jquery function for example I had a function

$(document).on("change", "#myid", function() {})

changed to

$(document).on("change", "#myid", function() {});

worked for me