# No element found when delete a record

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, firefox, jqgrid

JqGrid 4.6.

Everything works fine. The only thing is that when I open the Firefox debugger and go to the console. If I delete a record(click the trash icon, then the delete dialog pops out, click Delete button and the page is refreshed etc), the debugger warns me.

> no element found

The possible scripts are:

```
$(gridSelector).jqGrid('navGrid', pagerSelector,
            {
                //navbar options
                edit: true,
                editicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-pencil blue',
                add: true,
                addicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-plus-circle purple',
                del: true,
                delicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-trash-o red',
                search: true,
                searchicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-search orange',
                refresh: true,
                refreshicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-refresh green',
                view: true,
                viewicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-search-plus grey',
                beforeRefresh: function () {
                    grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                }
            },

            {
                //delete record form
                closeAfterDelete: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                mtype: 'DELETE',
                onclickSubmit: function (params, postdata) {
                    params.url = API_URL + 'DeleteVendor';
                },
                beforeShowForm: function (e) {
                    var form = $(e[0]);
                    if (form.data('styled')) return false;

                    form.closest('.ui-jqdialog').find('.ui-jqdialog-titlebar').wrapInner('<div class="widget-header" />');
                    styleDeleteForm(form);

                    form.data('styled', true);
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Also

```
function styleDeleteForm(form) {
            var buttons = form.next().find('.EditButton .fm-button');
            buttons.addClass('btn btn-sm btn-white btn-round').find('[class*="-icon"]').hide(); //ui-icon, s-icon
            buttons.eq(0).addClass('btn-danger').prepend('<i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o"></i>');
            buttons.eq(1).addClass('btn-default').prepend('<i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i>');
        }
```

Although the error has not impacted my result. I can't locate the warning. I want remove it.

**EDIT:**

I tried it in google chrome. It seems okay. Maybe it is the bug in Firefox?

Comment: It has no sense to analyse the problem in jqGrid 4.6. You can debug the code step by step using Firefox developer tools to locate the problem, but it could be that the problem already fixed in many later versions of jqGrid 4.6. You can try whether you have the same problem if you temporary change the URLs of jqGrid to free jqGrid 4.12.1 or the latest source from GitHub (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). If you would have still close problem in free jqGrid I can try to help you.

Comment: @Oleg, using your free jqGrid 4.12.1, the problem is still persistent. Yes, I guess that is the Firefox issue. Some [thoughts here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386078/firebug-error-no-element-found).

Comment: Could you prepare the demo which demonstrates the problem? Just deleting one or many record in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa.htm) for example don't display any "no element found" message.

Comment: @Oleg, it is a good idea. Let's do the first step, generate the demo data in the repository. Please see [jqGridDemo.zip](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=3A8BB9EAEEFF1DB%214159&cid=03A8BB9EAEEFF1DB). I use your free-jqgrid framework, however I can't see some icons on the pager.

Comment: @Oleg, by the way. The web api code is from [here.](http://techbrij.com/add-edit-delete-jqgrid-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: Look at [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/ProductStore.zip). We are still at the common stage of usage free jqGrid. Can we go back to the problem "no element found"?

Comment: @Oleg, thanks for the correction. If you play it in Firefox, open F12 and click the console. Next if you delete the last row, you will find the [error](https://www.flickr.com/photos/67801243@N06/24850778512/in/dateposted-public/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating [the demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/ProductStore.zip) which can be used to reproduce "the problem" I can examine and describe it.

To reproduce the problem one need to start the MVC application and to use Firefox as frontend. One should start the integrated Debugger (by <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+S</kbd> or menu "Tools" / "Web Developer" / "Debugger") and to examine Browser Console window. The window contains many warnings, which are suspected for Firefox, but what are absolutely correct actions and the warnings are absolutely unneeded. After deleting of any row one will see the message like

[image]

I examined the problem exactly and it's really **wrong warning**, because of misinterpretation of HTTP traffic of REST operation. The DELETE method of ASP.NET MVC, which have `void` as return value (like `public void DeleteProduct(int id)`) produces the HTTP response like

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcT2xlZ1xEb3dubG9hZHNcUHJvZHVjdFN0b3JlXFByb2R1Y3RTdG9yZVxhcGlccHJvZHVjdHNcNA==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 12 Feb 2016 09:23:51 GMT
```

The bug of Firefox: **it displays message "no element found" for all HTTP responses which have no body**. Thus if the status code is `204` (No Content) or if the status code is `200` (OK), but the body is empty (there are exist HTTP header `Content-Length: 0`) then Firefox suspect that the REST resource is not found and it display the "warning" with the text "no element found".

If you don't want to see the message then you have to return some data in the body of DELETE response. For example

```
public HttpResponseMessage DeleteProduct(int id)
{
    bool isDeleted = _repository.Remove(id);
    if (!isDeleted) {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK!");
}
```

which produces the response like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcT2xlZ1xEb3dubG9hZHNcUHJvZHVjdFN0b3JlXFByb2R1Y3RTdG9yZVxhcGlccHJvZHVjdHNcNg==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 12 Feb 2016 09:05:19 GMT
Content-Length: 5

"OK!"
```

I personally think that one should better just ignore "the warning" of Firefox and to hold `public HttpResponseMessage DeleteProduct(int id)`. I would still recommend you to update the repository which you use to

```
interface IProductRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Product> GetAll();
    Product Get(int id);
    Product Add(Product item);
    bool Remove(int id);
    bool Update(Product item);
}
```

where `Remove` have Boolean as return type. The implementation can be

```
public bool Remove(int id)
{
    return _products.RemoveAll(p => p.Id == id) > 0;
}
```

and the MVC code

```
public void DeleteProduct(int id)
{
    _repository.Remove(id);
}
```

will be fixed to

```
public void DeleteProduct(int id)
{
    bool isDeleted = _repository.Remove(id);
    if (!isDeleted)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

I want to stress that all above problem is pure ASP.NET MVC problem or a problem of Firefox and it have no direct relation to free jqGrid or jqGrid.

You can download the modified project [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/ForStackOverflow/ProductStore1.zip). The `ProductsController.cs` file contains commented version of `DeleteProduct`, which don't produce any warning in Firefox. You can play with the code by changing the dummy text `"OK!"` to the empty string `""` or some other tests. The Firefox bug is very old (it's origin seams be [the Bug 521301](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=521301)).

Comment: Thanks again. Nice help.

Comment: By the way, how did you find the Http response information such as `HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache`? In F12, the response is empty. I mean which tools did you use? Fideler4?

Comment: @Love: I used Raw view of responses in [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), but the same information can be found in Developer Tools of IE, Chrome and Firefox. One need just make more clicks. Moreover I uses Fiddler since very long time and like it. I use Developer Tools only to see HTTPS or HTTP2 traffic.