# Free jgGrid show add button on pager

Tags: jquery, arrays, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am setting up a simple jqGrid, and will have inline editing and deleting, but now trying to make the add button show up on the pager.  I will start with the default add action, but I can't seem to remember how to make the add button show there, and I would like to know the clean way to do it on free jqGrid.

Here is the current code.  Thanks.

```
$('#press_op_setup').jqGrid({
        url:'grid.php',
        postData:{
            'arg1':'press_ops'
        },
        height: 'auto',
        datatype: 'xml',
        mtype: 'POST',
        width: 400,
        colNames:[
            'id',
            'Emp Num'
        ],
        colModel:[
            {name: 'id', hidden: true, key: true},
            {name: 'empnum'}
        ],
        inlineEditing: {addRow: {}},
        sortname: 'empnum',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: 'Press Operators',
        rowNum: 100,
        pager: true
    });
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I correctly understand what you need. You should call at least `inlineNav` method or both `navGrid` and `inlineNav`. You can replace the `});` symbols at the end of call of `$('#press_op_setup').jqGrid({...});` to `.jqGrid("navGrid")..jqGrid("inlineNav");`. You can add additional options to jqGrid: `navOptions: { add: false, edit: false, search: false, refresh: false }` and `inlineNavOptions: { add: true, edit: true }`. Is it what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I correctly understand what you need. You should call at least `inlineNav` method or both `navGrid` and `inlineNav`. You can call the methods directly after creating the grid. Using `navOptions` and `inlineNavOptions` you can specify additional options of `navGrid` and `inlineNav`. Alternatively you can use the same options directly as the options of `navGrid` and `inlineNav` methods.

One thing with isn't work in simple way: reordering of buttons inside of navigator bar (pager). You still can move the DOM elements using jQuery methods like `append`, `prepend` and so on. For example, your code could be the following:

```
$('#press_op_setup').jqGrid({
    url:'grid.php',
    postData:{
        'arg1':'press_ops'
    },
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'POST',
    width: 400,
    colNames:[
        'id',
        'Emp Num'
    ],
    colModel:[
        //{name: 'id', hidden: true, key: true},
        {name: 'empnum'}
    ],
    inlineEditing: { keys: true },
    sortname: 'empnum',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Press Operators',
    rowNum: 100,
    pager: true,
    navOptions: { add: false, edit: false, search: false, refresh: false },
    inlineNavOptions: { add: true, edit: true }
}).jqGrid("navGrid")
    .jqGrid("inlineNav");
$("#press_op_setup_iladd").prependTo($("#press_op_setup_iladd").parent());
```

I removed unneeded hidden `id` column. The `id` attribute of rows (`<tr>` elements) will be set already. One don't need to hold the copy of the same information in hidden `<td>` element of the grid.

I removed unneeded `height: 'auto'` and `gridview: true` options, which are default for free jqGrid. Empty `addRow: {}` inside of `inlineEditing` is unneeded too. You should specify only the properties, which you really need to set like `keys: true` above.

Comment: So, for example, in this fiddle, I would want there to be a plus button for add in the pager, but it seems using these additional steps the button still doesn't show up.  https://jsfiddle.net/yks2rawL/

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: Sorry, I described the call of `navGrid` and `inlineNav` in my answer and in the comment to your question before, but forgot to add the call in the code of my answer. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yks2rawL/1/

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: I changed the demo additionally to use the latest version of free jqGrid: 4.15.0

Comment: OK great yeah i was thinking I was missing a call to something like that, although it seems that including the inlineNavOptions implies that you want to trigger an `inlineNav`.  Or just like you have the `pager: true` options, there could be an `inlineNav: true`, and `navGrid: true` options of the jqgrid definition.  Just some thoughts.  Thanks a lot!