# ASP.NET Modal Popup only displays grayed out page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, modalpopup

edit: [link to error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFMSs.jpg)

I am new to `ASP.NET`, I cannot get Modal Popup to work, I think it has to do with including the right scripts in `_Layout`, but after extensive searching I cannot find a way to get more than a grayed out overlay over the view.

**_Layout**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
      @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryajax") ;
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
</head>
<body>
<div class="container body-content">
 @RenderBody()
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</div>
```

**Index**

```
<div id="modal1" class='modal fade in'>
<div id="modal2">
</div>
</div>
 <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click to popup"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("Modal")',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#modal2").html(data);
                $("#modal1").modal('show');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: First thing to is press F12 and inspect the console tab for javascript errors, and also the network tab for ajax post errors

Comment: I'm getting **no element found error**, I'm not sure if its a js error or ajax error

Comment: is it in the console? Does it have a .js file listed next to it? I'm not sure if it is the intention but you have your divs nested - is that on purpose? I've never used jquery ui modals like that before. I suggest you start with a simpler implementation and work up - just use one div and one modal

Comment: and I'm not sure if `@Url` works inside javascript - that razor I think

Comment: Referring to this (first hit when I search on your error) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386078/firebug-error-no-element-found this is a javascript error. You need to check the network tab, which represents your HTTP calls and see if your url `@Url.Action("Modal")` is working as expected - is it being called and is it returning data?

Comment: Also right click and inspect your index page and observe the javascript code and see if @Url.Action has resolved to the expected URL

Comment: I have edited the post to include a link to the picture.'@URl.Action("Home")' resolves to /Home/Modal, and inspecting the element I see that the Modal is inserted inside div id=Modal2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(Via data attributes):**

Activate a modal without writing JavaScript. Set `data-toggle="modal"` on a controller element, like a button, along with a `data-target="#foo"` or `href="#foo"` to target a specific modal to toggle.

**You can try this**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">show my modal </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
         <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-body">This is my content</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  <!-- /.modal -->
```

**Via JavaScript**

Call a modal with id myModal with a single line of JavaScript:

```
   $('#myModal').modal(options)
```

Comment: This actually works! I have never gotten this close. In your code example you included two buttons, obviously both buttons are not needed. Now, can I accomplish the same modal popup, with myModal in a different view that can be called from a controller, and populated with a strongly typed Model?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML for your modal popup doesn't look right.Please have a look below how a bootstrap modal popup should look and an example of displaying it using jQuery:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btn").click(function () {
                var data = "Some test data...";
                $(".modal-body").html(data);
                $("#modal1").modal('show');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="click" />
    <!--Modal start-->
    <div id="modal1" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal popup</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal end-->
</body>
```

**Output:**

[image: Displaying data in bootstrap popup]